# Python; run scipt in all subfolders

Tags: python

I have a python script, which works fine if I run it in the folder that contains the files that I need. But I want to change the script, that it will go into each subfolder, use the files per subfolder, and write a output file in each subfolder. 
I have read about os.walk etc, but I do not understand how to change my script that os.walk will work. Please help me. 
The script is al follows:

```
d1 = {}
with open('genes.gff.genespercontig.csv', 'r') as f:
for line in f:
        tok = line.split()
        d1[tok[1]] = int(float(tok[0]))

d2 = {}
with open('hmmer.analyze.txt.result.txt', 'r') as f2:
    for line in f2:
        tak = line.split()
        d2[tak[1]] = int(float(tak[0]))

from itertools import chain
from collections import defaultdict
d3 = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in chain(d1.items(), d2.items()):
    d3[k].append(v)

import csv    
with open('output_contigsvsgenes.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)    
    for k,v in d3.items():
        writer.writerow([k] + v)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know that each file you're trying to read will be available in each directory in the tree then you can simply wrap your current script in an os.walk block:

```
import os

for root, dirs, files in os.walk('.'):
    d1 = {}
    with open(os.path.join(root, 'genes.gff.genespercontig.csv'), 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            tok = line.split()
            d1[tok[1]] = int(float(tok[0]))

    d2 = {}
    with open(os.path.join(root, 'hmmer.analyze.txt.result.txt'), 'r') as f2:
        for line in f2:
            tak = line.split()
            d2[tak[1]] = int(float(tak[0]))

    from itertools import chain
    from collections import defaultdict
    d3 = defaultdict(list)
    for k, v in chain(d1.items(), d2.items()):
        d3[k].append(v)

    import csv
    with open(os.path.join(root, 'output_contigsvsgenes.csv'), 'w') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        for k,v in d3.items():
            writer.writerow([k] + v)
```

Otherwise you'll need to guard against the case in which the files you're looking for may not exist. Since it appears that you require values from both files to create your output, it's probably fine to wrap the entire thing in a try block:

```
import os

for root, dirs, files in os.walk('.'):
    try:
        d1 = {}
        with open(os.path.join(root, 'genes.gff.genespercontig.csv'), 'r') as f:
            for line in f:
                tok = line.split()
                d1[tok[1]] = int(float(tok[0]))

        d2 = {}
        with open(os.path.join(root, 'hmmer.analyze.txt.result.txt'), 'r') as f2:
            for line in f2:
                tak = line.split()
                d2[tak[1]] = int(float(tak[0]))

        from itertools import chain
        from collections import defaultdict
        d3 = defaultdict(list)
        for k, v in chain(d1.items(), d2.items()):
            d3[k].append(v)

        import csv
        with open(os.path.join(root, 'output_contigsvsgenes.csv'), 'w') as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f)
            for k,v in d3.items():
                writer.writerow([k] + v)
    except:
        print traceback.format_exc()
```

If you want to handle the individual files separately, then you can modify the above to handle the case in which one file but not the other is present.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but when I try this, I get the following error:               IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './genes.gff.genespercontig.csv'. I am very sure that the files are in each subdirectory, but it seems that the script cannot find them.

Comment: I've edited the second example to catch all errors, not just name errors. Hopefully that should take care of it. If you're sure the files are there but it's not able to find them, try printing the files variable to make sure they are in fact there.

Comment: I am sorry, but also the second example gives the same error

Comment: The second example works as intended for me. Obviously it's not able to find any of the files, but it shouldn't throw any errors if it's wrapped in a try / except. It just prints 'No file'.

Comment: Oh yes, my mistake, my apologies; it prints no file multiple times. Ahhh, what am I doing wrong, all subfolders contain the files that the script need.

Comment: Os.walk gives you three variables to work with, in the above examples called root, dirs, and files. These correspond to the relative path to the directory you're currently traversed to, a list of directories in that directory, and a list of files in that directory. Try printing out these variables to ensure that the walk is ending up in the directories you intend it to, and that the files you're trying to open are indeed there. Let me know what you find.

Comment: Thanks for your help!    I tried to print each step, and the problem was with the 'w' function. It could not find the file that was intent to be the new output file ("output_contigvsgenes.csv"). So, I changed in this line the "w" to 'w+', but now it works only for the first subfolder. For the other folders, I get still the message "no file".

Comment: It's entirely possible that the try / except is masking another error, I've updated the second example to still log out the traceback of a caught error. That should help you see if the problem is indeed missing the files, or if it's something else.